# How to Login to a ASP.NET application by knowing only encrypted password?

Tags: asp.net

I am very new to web application (ASP.NET). I have source code and database for a complete project.

ASP.NET (Authentication) control is used for login. I don't know the password right now but i can get the login name and password in encrypt format from the database table.
How could I login to the application with only this little information available.

As the control are dynamically created on the pages, it is very hard to debug and find them on runtime.

How could i proceed for login by encrypted password? or is there a way to login by overcoming Authentication control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password is probably SHA1 encrypted. Basically what you have to do is SHA1 encrypt the password the user gives you and compare that to the password in your database. Because SHA1 always results to the same thing if the input is the same, you will know that the users given password is correct if both hashes match.

SHA1 encryption is a form of hashing and cannot be reversed.

Comment: Users password is not given as of now.  Any alternatives?

Comment: You only need the encrypted version to log a user in.

Answer (score 1):

No, hashed passwords in the database are non-reversible intentionally. This keeps anyone (a hacker?) from reading your database and being able to log in.

As Sam152 said, the passwords are likely SHA1 hashed, so if the passwords are not stored with salt, you can build a rainbow table to find the original password. If they are salted, you need to know the salt to build the rainbow table as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try implementing custom `MembershipProvider` by derriving from this class. Then you just override method `ValidateUser` to meet your requirements. Also remember to modify Web.config.

Answer (score 0):

The point of hashed passwords is that a they can't be used by folks not knowing the decrypted password.

There should be a way to reset the password for users.  You could do this and log in based on the reset password.

If you are trying to log in to an active user's account, you may want to consider the implications in doing so without their knowledge (if that is the case).  However, if it is just a test user, reseting the password is probably the least cumbersome way.  That functionality or procedure should probably be part of web app anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the standard ASP.NET membership stuff, I think it uses a stored proc to check the DB. Just change that and have it return true or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above answers SHA1 encryption output is 40 byte.  You should check the length of the encrypted password to get an idea about the kind of encryption..since hash algorithm has predefined no of output bytes, this would help you map with the kind of algorithm and then you should look for possibile salt usage as @MattGWagner said...is the tables in database that stores user information seems like aspnet_users,aspnet_membership, etc? Then this should be the standard authentication provided by windows..Just google and see how it works